# I keep getting either "No match" or incorrect result in my google sheets function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am preparing a sheet for next year's vacation planning; however I've met a problem:
You can take 1 full day of vacation,
You also can take just half day.
Making function that would substract just 1 from the 25 is no problem (`=D5-COUNTIF(F5:AJ5; "D")`) as can be seen in the picture below:
[The first equation][image: 1]

But as aforementioned, I also need to substract just half a day (which could be considered as value 0,5), if filled as HD.
And on the top of that, I need to have the equation/function in one cell, so it would be done simultaneously.

So, if John decides to plan his vacation as "HD" on 2 January and "D" on 3 January, then the equation should be → 25-0,5-1=23,5.

Only solution I got after quite long research is this:

```
=D5-SUM(SWITCH(F5:AJ5; 1; "D"; 0,5; "HD"; "0,5"))
```

I keep getting incorrect result and if I delete the "0,5", I will get #N/A.

I am attaching the link to the document →
[The spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS-9jw1cHq_cgoTST_ZuJn8bkRAAsbpas0Af0Obu7bfzvKTkHpxEJfD_tzt_0qsdziK_3wDdQp09B7X/pubhtml)

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. Use [Markdown Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892)-all the data needed to answer your question must be in the question itself. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for `SWITCH` is

```
SWITCH(expression, case1, value if case1, case2, value if case2,... default)
```

Here the case is either `D` or `HD`. Your arguments are switched. The correct formula is

```
=D5-SUM(SWITCH(F5:AJ5; "D"; 1; "HD"; 0,5; 0))
```

You can also use two `COUNTIF` like

```
=D5-COUNTIF(F5:AJ5; "D")-COUNTIF(F5:AJ5; "HD")/2
```

Divide the final count by 2